# Сохранение картинок для Web

Tags: photoshop, html, вёрстка, css

Привет.
Какою величину параметра quality нужно выбирать при сохранении картинок для сайта?
Ведь можно сохранить картинку JPEG весом 28К а можно 2,8К. Что посоветуете?
И еще там есть 3 флажка:

- Progressive
- Optimized
- Embed color profile.

Какие флажки должны быть активированы?

Comment: "save for web" в photoshop идеальная вещь для этих нужд...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

51% - для блога, 75-80% - наиболее общий, 85-95% - для фотосайта.
Для иконок - вообще gif/png.

Во всех случаях смотрите глазами. Резкие переходы и границы должны быть видны.
Чем меньше размер, тем лучше.

Галки - progressive не стоит. Совместимость страдает. Остальное - смотрите как на качестве отразится.